# Zoom D3 JS version 5 coordinates to pixel

Tags: javascript, d3.js, leaflet

I'm working in a project to visualize position in a map using D3JS.

I'm using d3.geoMercator() to convert position to pixels.

here is my code:

```
var projection = d3.geoMercator()
    .scale(2600)
    .center([-1.16455 , 47.15237]) // Pan north 40 degrees
    .translate([width/2,height/2]);
```

then here is the drawing of the positions:

```
node = svg.selectAll("circle")
                .data(this.myData)
                .enter()
                .append("circle")
                .attr("class", "dot")
                .attr("r", 10)
                .attr("fill", this.col)
                .attr("transform", function(d) {
                  return "translate(" + projection([d.x,d.y]) + ")";});
```

the positions are displayed correctly, but when i tried to do some zoom in the map, the position doesn't behave in a correct way so they take the correct place.

I need to do dynamic convert of position each time the user make a zoom.

Here the code that i used to do the zoom:

```
var zoom = d3.zoom()
    .on("zoom", function() {
        this.node.attr("transform", d3.event.transform);
    });

svg.call(zoom);
```

Comment: Have you seen this? https://bl.ocks.org/roboojack/391d5030ad1a3e29959598c0854b2c5d

Comment: Yes but this is not what i'm looking about, the position have to react to the zoom and stays in there correct place, without making them smaller

Comment: Could you post a codepen/jsfiddle containing your code so we could take a further look?

Comment: Are you zooming by scaling the svg/g/path or are you altering the projection? Or do you use leaflet to scale?

Comment: This the behavior is what i'm looking for http://bl.ocks.org/nivas8292/bec8b161587cb62e9fda, its done by D3 version 3, i want to do the same thing but with D3 version 5, i'm getting lost cause there a lot of chages between the both versions, and i have to integrate this code in angular application

Comment: Can you share the zoom portion of your code?

Comment: var zoom = d3.zoom()
    .on("zoom", function() {
        this.node.attr("transform", d3.event.transform);
    });

svg.call(zoom);